# Replacing . with / in a Unix shell script

Tags: unix

I want to replace `.` with `/` in a Unix shell script:

`2015.07.25` to `2015/07/25`

How can I do this?

Comment: we need more context. Do you mean inside of a text file (or other kind of file, then specify) OR do you mean in the output of a  string `echo "2015.07.25"`. OR once your value is assigned to a variable, i.e. `myDate="2015.07.25"`. Please take 15 mins to read what you can when searching for `[unix] date reformat`, sorted by highest votes, and then update your question to make something answerable. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get the swiss army knife out to drive a small nail :)

```
echo "2015.07.25" | tr . /
```

Translates the character `.` to `/` .

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "2015.07.25"|sed "s/\./\//g"
```

Replacing the "." with "/". Used escape character ("\") to escape special meaning of the characters (. and / ).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` this says substituted for the characters in the site `[.]` (which is just the '.' char) a forward slash. The `g` at the end stands for "make this a **g**lobal substitution, not just replace the first instance.

```
echo "2015.07.25" | sed 's;[.];/;g'
```

**Result:**

> $ echo "2015.07.25" | sed 's;[.];/;g'
>
> 2015/07/25